# DAL-script is different between the one in github and pip install

Tags: pip, django-autocomplete-light

I am trying to follow the [Django-autocomplete-light tutorial](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html)
However, when I try to run the test_project, I get the following error.

> AttributeError: module 'dal.autocomplete' has no attribute
>   'Select2GenericForeignKeyModelField'

When I check the dal/autocomplete.py which was installed through pip command, I could not find any attribute Select2GenericForeignKeyModelField.
On the other hand, when I check the one in github, I could find this attribute.
I am guessing that the version which is in pip is older than the one in github.
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest stable version is DAL 3.2.10, it [was released at Aug 28, 2017](https://pypi.org/project/django-autocomplete-light/3.2.10/#files) and `Select2GenericForeignKeyModelField` [was added at Mar 30, 2018](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/commit/54ec74ed73796d21cc4fc919f425809c48a605d4). It's not available even in pre-releases as the most recent pre-release now is [3.3.0rc6](https://pypi.org/project/django-autocomplete-light/3.3.0rc6/#files) released at Mar 6, 2018.

It seems you have to use older API or install DAL from Github:

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light#egg=django-autocomplete-light
```